# Prove an inequality. Lagrange theorem and Taylor polynomials may be used

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion

$φ(t) = -θt + ln(1-θ + θe^t).$
Please show that $φ(t) ≤ \frac{1}{8}t^2$.
I have tried to compute the derivative in terms of t and theta and let them equal to zero.
However I get stuck and do know how to continue this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the Taylor expansion of $\varphi$ at $t=0$, with the Lagrange form remainder.

$$\varphi (t) = \varphi(0)+\varphi'(0)+\frac {\varphi''(\xi)}{2!}t^2$$

where $\xi \in (0, t)$.

We have

$$\varphi'(t)=-\theta+\frac {\theta e^t}{1-\theta+\theta e^t}$$
$$\varphi''(t)=\frac {\theta e^t(1-\theta+\theta e^t)-\theta e^t(\theta e^t)}{(1-\theta+\theta e^t)^2}=\frac {(1-\theta)\theta e^t}{(1-\theta+\theta e^t)^2}$$

It is easily seen that $\varphi (0) = \varphi'(0)=0$.

It remains to show that $\varphi''(\xi)\le \dfrac14$.

Write $a = 1-\theta$ and $b = \theta e^\xi$. Then

$$\varphi ''(\xi) = \frac {ab}{(a+b)^2} \le \frac{ab}{4ab} = \frac 14$$

This inequality is due to $$4ab \le 4ab + (a-b)^2 = (a+b)^2$$

and we are finally done.

Comment: Why $O(t^2)$ is ignored in the second line?

Comment: $\dfrac {\varphi''(\xi)}{2!}t^2$ is the explicit form of the Lagrange form remainder. This $\xi$ depends on $t$.

Comment: Oh, thank you! My fault.